# Не понимаю условие задачи

Tags: java

1. Напишите программу, вводящую целочисленное значение и выводящую его в двоичной, восьмеричной и шестнадцатеричной форме.
2. Организуйте вывод обратного значения в виде шестнадцатеричного числа с плавающей точкой.

Решил доделать задачи, которые раньше не осилил. Но до сих пор не могу понять 2-е условие

Comment: Понял вас! Спасибо вам! Ум за разум уже заходит. Обратное число...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мб речь идет об обратном числе к веденному?  (a=2 обратное 1/2?)
Нужно реализовать алгоритм нахождение обратного числа, алгоритмы есть на просторах интернета) Если не ошибаюсь, алгоритм Евклида называется.

А дальше дело техники)